# PayPal Integration using CocoaPods iOS

Tags: paypal-sandbox, cocoapods

Hi I create pod file in my mac , name of the pod file platform : ios, `6.0`
pod `PayPal-iOS-SDK` pod create successfully, but when I open .workspace and use paypal class . when I run code it give error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalConfiguration", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PayPalMainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalFuturePaymentViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PayPalMainViewController.o
```

Comment: I am also facing same issue have you got any solution...